# C++ type verification in generic programming

Tags: c++, generics, typeid

The aim is to write a generic template function who can calculate the distance between two points(take for example p1 and p2 as two parameters). The point can be represented in many ways:

```
hopp::vector2<double> p0(0.0, 0.0);
sf::Vector2<double> p1(0.0, 1.0);
std::array<double, 2> p2 = { 1.0, 1.0 };
std::vector<double> p3 = { 1.0, 0.0 };
wxRealPoint p4(1.0, -1.0);
QPointF p5(0.0, -1.0);
```

And the function should be like :

```
distance(p0,p1)
distance(p1,p2)
....
```

so my code goes like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include "hopp/vector2.hpp"
#include "Qt/qpoint.h"
#include "SFML/Vector2.hpp"
#include "wxWidgets/gdicmn.h"
template<class T1,class T2> auto distance2(T1 p1, T2 p2)
{
   auto x1 = 0.0;
   auto y1 = 0.0;
   auto x2 = 0.0;
   auto y2 = 0.0;
  /*
   * if p1 is a class.
   */


  if (typeid(p1).name() == typeid(Point<int>).name() ||
      typeid(p1).name() == typeid(Point<double>).name()||
      typeid(p1).name() == typeid(Point<float>).name() ||
      typeid(p1).name() == typeid(hopp::vector2<double>).name() ||
      typeid(p1).name() == typeid(sf::Vector2<double>).name() ||
      typeid(p1).name() == typeid(wxRealPoint).name() ||
      typeid(p1).name() == typeid(QPointF).name()
    ) {
       x1 = p1.x;
       y1 = p1.y;
  }
  /*
  * if p1 is a array or vector.
  */
  else if(   typeid(p1).name() == typeid(std::array<double, 2>).name()
   ||
             typeid(p1).name() == typeid(std::vector<double>).name() ||
             typeid(p1).name() == typeid(std::array<int>).name() ||
             typeid(p1).name() == typeid(std::vector<int>).name() ||
             typeid(p1).name() == typeid(std::array<float>).name() ||
             typeid(p1).name() == typeid(std::vector<float>).name()

           ){
      x1 = p1[0];
      y1 = p1[1];
  }

  if (  typeid(p2).name() == typeid(Point<int>).name() ||
        typeid(p2).name() == typeid(Point<double>).name()||
        typeid(p2).name() == typeid(Point<float>).name() ||
        typeid(p2).name() == typeid(hopp::vector2<double>).name() ||
        typeid(p2).name() == typeid(sf::Vector2<double>).name() ||
        typeid(p2).name() == typeid(wxRealPoint).name() ||
        typeid(p2).name() == typeid(QPointF).name()
  )
  {
     x2 = p2.x;
     y2 = p2.y;
  } else if (typeid(p2).name() == typeid(std::array<double, 2>).name()
       ||
             typeid(p2).name() == typeid(std::vector<double>).name() ||
             typeid(p2).name() == typeid(std::array<int>).name() ||
             typeid(p2).name() == typeid(std::vector<int>).name() ||
             typeid(p2).name() == typeid(std::array<float>).name() ||
             typeid(p2).name() == typeid(std::vector<float>).name()

         ){
       x2 = p2[0];
       y2 = p2[1];
  }


  auto diff_x = x1-x2;
  auto diff_y = y1-y2;

  return sqrt(pow(diff_x,2)+pow(diff_y,2));
}
```

There are many errors when compiling and I don't think it's a good proposition to do many type verification using 'typeid'. How should I deal with this problem?

Comment: Why a template function cant you just overload it?

Comment: Personally I would write a `get_points` function.  It is overloaded for all the types you want to support and you handle the logic of how to extract the data from the type in the function.  Then in the generic function you just call get points to get the data and then calculate the distance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid tons of overloads use sfinae mechanism e.g. as follows ([live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/WpznoJpSUlxB2vzy)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

struct Point {
    double x;
    double y;
};

template <class T>
auto getX(T t) -> decltype(t.x) {
    return t.x;
}

template <class T>
auto getX(T t) -> decltype(t[0]) {
    return t[0];
}

template <class T>
auto getY(T t) -> decltype(t.y) {
    return t.y;
}

template <class T>
auto getY(T t) -> decltype(t[1]) {
    return t[1];
}

template <class T1, class T2>
auto distance(T1 p1, T2 p2) {
    auto x1 = getX(p1);
    auto x2 = getX(p2);
    auto y1 = getY(p1);
    auto y2 = getY(p2);
    auto diff_x = x1-x2;
    auto diff_y = y1-y2;

    return sqrt(pow(diff_x,2)+pow(diff_y,2));
}



int main() {
    Point p1;
    std::vector<double> p2 = {1, 2};
    std::cout << distance(p1, p2) << std::endl;
}
```

This should work independently of the point type as long as the type does not have `x` member and at the same time overloaded `operator[]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I have test the code, it goes well when the x and y is public in a point. When x and y are private ,just add two functions using decltype(t.getPrivateX())  to get them.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to combine a templated function with overloaded functions for extracting the x and y values:

```
template<typename T1,typename T2>
auto distance(T1 p1, T2 p2)
{
  const auto x1 = getX(p1);
  const auto y1 = getY(p1);
  const auto x2 = getX(p2);
  const auto y2 = getY(p2);

  const auto diff_x = x1 - x2;
  const auto diff_y = y1 - y2;

  return sqrt(pow(diff_x, 2) + pow(diff_y, 2));
}

auto getX(const std::vector<double>& v)
{
  return v[0];
}

auto getX(const Point<double>& v)
{
  return v.x;
}

...
```

To reduce the number of overloaded functions you could make the getters return std::tuple:

```
template<typename T1,typename T2>
auto distance(T1 p1, T2 p2)
{
  const auto p1_pair = get_values(p1);
  const auto p2_pair = get_values(p2);

  const auto diff_x = std::get<0>(p1_pair) - std::get<0>(p2_pair);
  const auto diff_y = std::get<1>(p1_pair) - std::get<1>(p2_pair);

  return sqrt(pow(diff_x, 2) + pow(diff_y, 2));
}

auto get_values(const std::vector<double>& v)
{
  return std::make_tuple(v[0], v[1]);
}

auto get_values(const Point<double>& v)
{
  return std::make_tuple(v.x, v.y);
}

...
```